# Asp.net LocalDB (SQL) Login Failed for user 'SQLLogin'

Tags: asp.net, localdb

Overall Goal is to create a webapp that has a local DB that multiple people from outside the network can access at one time.

I am trying to use a SQL Login for the connection string for a local DB in my asp.net website. When trying to access the site locally from development I get.

Cannot open database "|DataDirectory|\tatcrm.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'TatUser'.

I am using the following connection string in web.config:

```
<add name="Tattoo" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=|DataDirectory|\tatcrm.mdf;User ID=TatUser;Password=SecretPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Inside the LocalDB I have used the following to create a Login & User.
While using the tatcrm DB:

```
CREATE LOGIN TatUser WITH PASSWORD = 'SecretPassword';
CREATE USER TatUser FOR LOGIN TatUser;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'TatUser'
```

The login and User are created but when I try to connect It says invalid login. What is going on here? What am I missing?

Authentication Mode is mixed as well.
[Mix Mode Authentication Set True Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRcVs.png)

[Screenshot of localDB in asp.net project and the users/login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfo91.png)

I have tried creating the DB in SSMS first then move over to App_Data to check if the user worked. See images Below.

[New SQL Db created in SSMS to test TatUser works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkkZm.png)

[Now TatUser does not work in VS when migrated DB over to App_Data Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pVLV.png)

Comment: Is the SQL Server server configured to use SQL Authentication (or Mixed-Mode Authentication)?

Comment: @Dai - I have verified that it is set to Mixed Mode. I added the screenshot to the main post.

Comment: Try to login using MS SQL Server Management Studio and let us know if working or not using same authentications parameters and server name.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem I was unable to attach it to SSMS due to a version difference on the DB. So I created a new one in SSMS. I then tested the TatUser (See new image above) and was able to connect in SSMS, but when I moved the DB over to the App_Data folder, I was unable to connect to it in VS. Please see image above.

Comment: @GrimRieber can you try windows auth using this connection string and let me know your feedback ? "Server=(localdb)\\Test;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName= myDbFile;" ?? Anyway, I think you have two sql server installs on your pc, so make sure that your connection string is correct , I suggest to use maangment tool pleae install it and try connect to make sure that you are using the correct server name

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem That works locally from Visual Studios, but when I test it from the outside I receive the following error. Unable to open the physical file "C:\Websites\Tattoo\TatCRM\App_Data\TatCRM.mdf". Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Websites\Tattoo\TatCRM\App_Data\TatCRM.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem I've updated my original post to show what the goal I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to make this work. I just ended up using a DB from the localhost's SQLServer instead of having a Local DB. Works as intended, but it would have been nice to have the DB attached to the web application.

Thank you all for your help in trying to get this to work for me.